# php loop is not working in a .php file

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a php loop as follows:

```
<?php
for ($i= 0; $i < 18; $i++)
{
echo "hello World";
echo "</br>";
} 
?>
```

when I run it I get this as an output:

```
"; } ?>
```

However when I used http://www.writephponline.com/ I get the expected output.

I'm using notepad++ and chrome. The file has a .php ext.

Is there something missing?

Surely it is a silly mistake but can't figure it out. I appreciate your help.

Comment: How do you access this file in the browser? Is a PHP engine running?

Comment: is this your full code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be running a web server with php installed. You appear to be loading the file directly from a server with no php installed, or as a file directly, without a server.
Your file is being interpreted as HTML not PHP

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the php interpreter....
As you are using windows, you can take a look to WAMP to setup a working php enviroment http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Answer (score 0):

browser can't run your php code.

here is a way that you could run your php code :

```
 1. open terminal  
 2. go to the directory where your file exist
 3. type this command "php -S localhost:8000"
```

now open your browser and goto `http://localhost:8000/YOUR_FILE_NAME.php"` **or** just `http://localhost:8000/` if the file name is `index.php`

> **NOTE** : you should have php installed in your computer